Example of non-unital ring where the additive neutral element is not asorbing for multiplication
I can prove that in every unital ring (or more generally in every unital semiring where the additive monoid is cancellative) the additive neutral element 0 is absorbing, meaning that a.0=0=0.a for every a, but my proof does not work without a neutral element for multiplication.
So my question  is, "Is it possible to have a non-unital ring where the additive neutral element is not absorbing" ?

If you are asking about rings, the answer is "no" because that is a consequence of ring axioms (without assuming identity).  Your question must be restricted to semirings.

thank you. So I would be interested with semiring examples.

Then edit and fix the title/question to ask what you really want to ask.

the real question is "Is it possible to have a non cancellative or non-unital semiring such that 0 is absorbing for the muliplication" ?

Put "the real question" in the post, explicitly. Don't bury it in the comments.

In a non-unital semiring $A$ we still have distributivity which still gives us that
$$0 \cdot a + 0 \cdot a = (0 + 0) \cdot a = 0 \cdot a$$
and similarly for $a \cdot 0$, hence both of these products must be additively idempotent. This gives us that $0 \cdot a = a \cdot 0 = 0$ if the additive monoid is cancellative with no use of a multiplicative identity.
For a counterexample when the additive monoid is not cancellative, consider $A = \{ 0, 1 \}$ with idempotent addition given by $\max$, so that $0 + 0 = 0$ and $0 + 1 = 1 + 0 = 1 + 1 = 1$. We can consider the somewhat strange multiplication which is just identically equal to $1$. Since $1 + 1 = 1$ and every product is equal to $1$, distributivity is satisfied for kind of silly reasons. And $0$ is not absorbing.
(Personally I consider this somewhat perverse, and IMO the real problem is that the definition of distributivity must be corrected in this case. What it should say is that multiplication is bilinear in each variable, meaning that $a \cdot (-)$ and $(-) \cdot a$ should be monoid homomorphisms, and in particular should preserve the additive identity by definition. If you don't care about this condition then you might as well throw out the additive identity too.)

Thank you. So that the fact that the additive monoid is cancellative is sufficient for the additive 0 to be absorbing.
